# How to Group Data Based on payment_id Only for Orders Data that is still in "1 or Menunggu Pembayaran" Status?

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-8

How to group data based on payment_id only for orders data that is still in "1 or Menunggu Pembayaran" status?

So, I want to create 1 API Resource for the following two designs.
[image]

If the order status is still waiting for payment (or Menunggu Pembayaran), the card is displayed and retrieves data from the payments table.

[image]

However, if the order status is not "Waiting for payment or Menunggu Pembayaran", the card displayed is fetched from the orders table.

How do I create an endpoint like this?

The following code that have I create;

```php
public function getPaymentOrder(Request $request)
{
    try {
        $user       = $request->user();

        $start_date = $request->start_date
                        ? Carbon::parse($request->start_date)->toDateTimeString()
                        : Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();
        
        $end_date   = $request->end_date
                        ? Carbon::parse($request->end_date)->toDateTimeString()
                        : Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();
        
        $subdays    = Carbon::today()->subDays($request->subdays)->toDateTimeString();

        $paymentId  = $user->payments()->pluck('id')->toArray();

        $orders     = Order::query()
                    ->whereIn('payment_id', $paymentId)
                    ->when($request->status, function ($query) use ($request) { // Filter by status
                        return $query->where('order_status', $request['status']);
                    })
                    ->when($request->start_date || $request->end_date, function ($query) use ($start_date,$end_date) { // Filter by start date and end date
                        return $query->whereBetween('created_at', [$start_date, $end_date]);
                    })
                    ->when($request->subdays, function ($query) use ($subdays) { // Filter by subdays
                        return $query->where('created_at', '>=', $subdays);
                    })
                    ->when($request->category_id, function ($query) use ($request) { // Filter by category id
                        $query->whereHas('details', function ($query) use ($request) {
                            $query->whereHas('product', function ($query) use ($request) {
                                $query->whereHas('subcategory', function ($query) use ($request) {
                                    return $query->where('category_id', $request->category_id);
                                });
                            });
                        });
                    })
                    ->latest()->paginate(10);

        return $this->respondSuccess('Success', TransactionResource::collection($orders));

    } catch (\Exception$err) {
        return $this->respondInternalError($err->getMessage());
    }
}
```

**TransactionResource**

```php
public function toArray($request)
{
    // Get order details
    $details        = $this->details->first();

    $productCount   = $this->details()->count();
    $subtitle       = $productCount > 1 ? '+ ' . ($productCount - 1) .' produk lainnya' : null;

    return [
        'id'                => $this->id,
        'status'            => config('data.order_status.'.$this->order_status),
        'payment_method'    => $this->paymentDetail->payment->paymentMethod->name ?? null,
        'transaction_code'  => $this->paymentDetail->payment->transaction_code
                                ? $this->paymentDetail->payment->transaction_code.'/'.$this->id
                                : null,
        'recipient_name'    => $this->recipient->name ?? null,
        'courier'           => $this->shipping_code ?? null,
        'city'              => $this->recipient->subdistrict->city ?? null,
        'cover'             => $details->product->cover ?? null,
        'title'             => $details->product->name ?? null,
        'subtitle'          => $subtitle,
        'order_date'        => Carbon::parse($this->created_at)
                                ->locale('id')
                                ->isoFormat('D MMMM Y, hh:mm'),
        'total_price'       => 'Rp. ' . number_format($this->total_payment, 0, ',', '.').',-',
        'note'              => $this->note ?? null,
        'created_at'        => Carbon::parse($this->created_at)->toDateTimeString(),
        'payment_id'        => $this->order_status == 1
                                ? $this->paymentDetail->payment->id
                                : null,
        'payment_icon'      => $this->paymentDetail->payment->paymentMethod->image
                                ? asset('storage/'.$this->paymentDetail->payment->paymentMethod->image)
                                : null,
        'payment_name'      => $this->paymentDetail->payment->paymentMethod->name ?? null,
        'account_name'      => $this->paymentDetail->payment->paymentMethod->account_name ?? null,
        'account_number'    => $this->paymentDetail->payment->paymentMethod->account_number ?? null,
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**.

I've fixed this case by creating a new endpoint to get payment data which is "Pending Payment" status